# (C++/winsock) Packaging alternative to structs

Tags: c++, winsock, packet

I have always used structs for packaging and receiving packets, will i gain anything by converting them to classes inherited from main packet class ?  is there another "c++ish" way for packaging and any performance gain by this ?

Comment: A struct is a class is a struct. Your question needs more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It is very general and various solutions may be available. This is related to Serialization topic and what you say is a simple model of serialization where packets contains structs which they can be loaded directly into memory and vice versa. I think C and C++ are great in this case because they allow you to write something like struct directly to stream and read it back easily. In other languages you can implement your byte alignment or you should serialize objects to be able to write them to streams.

In some cases you need to read a string stream like XML, SOAP, etc. In some application you should use structs. In some cases you need to serialize your objects into stream. It depends. But I think using structs and pointers is more forward than using object serialization.

In your case, you have 2 structures for each entity I think. A struct which moved along wire or file and a class which holds the entity instance inside memory. If you use binary serialization for your object, you can use just a class for sending, receiving and keeping the instance.

Answer (score 1):

### Data modelling

Generally, your C++ classes should factor the redundancy in the data they model.  So, if the packets share some common layout, then you can create a class that models that data and the operations on it.  You may find it convenient to derive classes that add other data members reflecting the hierarchy of possible packet data layouts, but other times it may be equally convenient to have unrelated classes reflecting the different layouts of parts of the packet (especially if the length or order of parts of the message can vary).

To give a clearer example of the simplest case fitting in with your ideas - if you have a standard packet header containing say a record id, record size in bytes and sequence id, you might reasonably put those fields into a class, and publicly derive a class for each distinct record id.  The base class might have member functions to read those values while converting from network byte order to the local byte order, check sequence ids are incrementing as needed etc. - all accessible to derived classes and their users.

### Runtime polymorphism

You should be wary of virtual members though - in almost all implementations they will introduce virtual dispatch pointers in your objects that will likely prevent them mirroring the data layout in the network packets.  If there's a reason to want run-time polymorphism (and there can easily be, especially when reading packets), you may find it useful to have a polymorphic hierarchy of classes having 1:1 correspondences with the hierarchy of non-polymorphic data-layout classes, and just containing a pointer to the location of the data in memory.

### Performance

Using a class or struct with layout deliberately mirroring your network packets potentially lets you operate on that memory in-place and very conveniently, trusting the compiler to create efficient code to do so.  Compilers are normally pretty good at that.

The *efficiency* (speed) of that access should be totally *unaffected* by the hierarchy of classes you use to model the data.  The data offsets involved and calls to non-virtual functions will all be resolved at compile-time.

You may see performance degredation if you introduce virtual functions as they can prevent inlining and require an extra pointer indirection, but you should put that in context by considering how else and how often you'd have switched between the layout-specific operations you need to support (for example, using `switch (record_id)` all over the place, `if (record_id == X)`, or explicit function pointers).